# Solidity + web3 js Why amount stay 0 with this simple deposit function

Tags: solidity, web3js

I publsh and initialize this sm

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract CommunityChest {
    function withdraw() public {
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function deposit(uint256 amount) payable public {
        require(msg.value == amount);
        // nothing else to do!
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    } 
}
```

with web3 js i intialize my contract and try to deposit 1 ether to contract adresse with the "desposit" function

```
var value = 1;
var params = {
gas: 40000,
from: userAccount
};
myContract.deposit(value, params, function(error, result){
    if(!error){
        console.log(result);
    }else{
        console.error(error);
    }
  });
```

Why my amount stay at 0 on Metamask ?

[image: function amount stay to 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually attach ether to the transaction. (Passing `1` as the parameter to the function does not do anything relating to ether. It's just a number.)

Use the `value` field` in the transaction options:

```
 var params = {
   gas: 40000,
   from: userAccount,
   value: value,
 };
```

Note that MetaMask will *still* probably show 0 ETH, because `value` is in wei, and 1 wei is 0.000000000000000001 ether. I don't think MetaMask can show values that small, so it will probably get rounded down to 0. But the call should work.

**EDIT**

Answering your follow-up question. From https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/15/writing-a-contract-that-handles-ether/:

> While `deposit()` can be trivially implemented like it was above, it’s a better practice to have the function take as a parameter the amount to be transferred and then to test that that’s the actual amount transferred. This allows the contract to reject transactions that may be erroneous.

Specifically, this line is what checks to make sure the amount you passed (`amount`) is the same as the amount of ether you attached to the transaction (`msg.value`):

```
require(msg.value == amount);
```

Comment: it work, thanks with this value i can see 0.1 ether

var value = 100000000000000000;

Comment: FYI, `web3.toWei(0.1, 'ether')` is a convenient way to get that number.